# Relative path does not work in child_process / node

Tags: node.js, gulp

Below is the current code I use in a Gulp task to run a bat file. The path is absolute.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

module.exports = function() {

    // Merges the CSS and JS files

    return exec("C:/git/xxxx/Config/BuildScripts/buildassets.bat",
        function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
        }
    );

};
```

I want to make it as relative path, but when I change it to a relative path,

```
return exec('../../../Config/BuildScripts/buildassets.bat'
```

I get the following error:

> '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How can I reference this file relatively?

Comment: maybe `cmd /C "../../../Config/BuildScripts/buildassets.bat"`. Not 100% sure as it is exec.

Comment: Do you mean like

    return exec(cmd /C "../../../Config/BuildScripts/buildassets.bat",
        function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
        }
    );

That didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I am doing this for that purpose but in my main process not in gulp file.

```
const app = electron.app;
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

var path = app.getAppPath();
exec(`"${path}\\path\\toexe.exe"`, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
   console.log(stdout);
   console.log(stderr);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `/`, use `\\`:

```
return exec('..\\..\\..\\Config\\BuildScripts\\buildassets.bat', function() {
  ...
})
```